# Необходимо отсортировать vector<string> по длине слов C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, visual-studio, visual-c++, сортировка

Задача состоит в том, что необходимо отсортировать `vector<string>` по длине элементов, находящихся в нём.
Вектор состоит из слов типа `string`. Как это реализовать эффективнее всего?

```
 #include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    vector<string> arr;
    string str("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
    string delim(" ");
    size_t prev = 0;
    size_t next;
    size_t delta = delim.length();

    while ((next = str.find(delim, prev)) != (string::npos)) 
    {
        arr.push_back(str.substr(prev, next - prev));
        prev = next + delta;
    }

    arr.push_back(str.substr(prev));

    for(int i = 0; i<arr.size();i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
vector<string> arr;

sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),
     [](const string& a, const string& b)
     { return a.length() < b.length(); });
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы немного разъяснить принцип роботы данной функции, либо оставить ссылку на ресурс, где можно почитать  об этом?

Comment: @АндрейЧереватов
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score -1):

Вся программа,  может и не самая, но намного эффективней:

```
using std::string;
using std::string_view;
string str("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
using In =  std::istream_iterator<string>;
std::istringstream is(str);
std::vector<string> arr{ In(is), In() };
std::stable_sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
    [](string_view s1, string_view s2) 
      { return s1.size() < s2.size(); });
```